# Insert text to specific position of a file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

im newb in scripting\programming. I'm writing a script that will change parameters in configuration file and then start the daemon. I have a problem with paste variable content (string) into a specific position of file. 
There is **'username'** word in that file by default and i has defined specific username into variable, how i can replace that 'username' with variable content?
Please give me advice.

Comment: Something like `sed -i 's/username/new_user_name/' daemon.conf`. Option `-i` is for _inplace replacement_ so you don't have to write a new file and then rename it. Be careful though, this option is not always available. Check it by reading the manual : `man sed`.

Comment: How i can select line number and character position in string using sed?

Comment: Why do you need to select the line number in your specific case ? In the script @maxime.bochon gave you,  `sed` will automatically locate the word `username` and replace it with `new_user_name`

Comment: Thank you, it worked with username. But now i have problem with password substitution, because there is several **password** keyword instances in a file. So command like **sed -i 's/password/$UsrPass/' <filename>**, replace all instances. How i could replace only one word?